# Comparing dates using m-d-Y format

Tags: php

I have dates `$current, $start` and $end formatted in m-d-Y. I want to have a condition 
wherein it will display "current" if current date is between start and end date BUT I just can't figure it out why in the world it will not print what i wanted. haha

sample declaration would be

```
$current = '07-03-2014';
$start = '06-01-2013';
$end = '08-02-2015';

    if(($current > $start) && ($current < $end)) {
    echo "current";
    }
    else {
    "not current";
    }
```

how come I have "not current" as output? what did I do wrong? I'm pretty sure you also have this problem. :D

Comment: strtotime dates and then compare

Comment: You could try putting your dates in the internationally standard format of `Y-m-d`

Comment: then how about these: $current = '2014-07-03'; $start = '2014-03-17'; $end = '2015-03-16'; how come it will still output "not current

Answer (score 1):

you can directly compare with correct format `Y-m-d`  or use `strtotime()`

```
$current = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('07-03-2014'));
 $start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('06-01-2013'));
 $end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('08-02-2015'));
 if(($current > $start) && ($current < $end)) {
    echo "current";
 }
 else {
    "not current";
 }
```

Comment: then how about these: $current = '2014-07-03'; $start = '2014-03-17'; $end = '2015-03-16'; how come it will still output "not current

Answer (score 0):

you can try this with `strtotime`

```
$current = '07-03-2014';
$start = '06-01-2013';
$end = '08-02-2015';

    if((strtotime($current) > strtotime($start)) && (strtotime($current) < strtotime($end))) {
    echo "current";
    }
    else {
        echo  "not current";
    }
```

**METHOD : 2**

```
$current = '07-03-2014';
$start = '06-01-2013';
$end = '08-02-2015';


$current_time = strtotime($current);
$start_time = strtotime($start);
$end_time = strtotime($end);

    if(($current_time > $start_time) && ($current_time < $end_time)) {
    echo "current";
    }
    else {
     echo  "not current";
    }
```

Comment: then how about these:
$current = '2014-07-03';
$start = '2014-03-17';
$end = '2015-03-16';

how come it will still output "not current"

Answer (score 0):

Use strtotime:

```
$current = '07-03-2014';
$start = '06-01-2013';
$end = '08-02-2015';
    if((strtotime($current) > strtotime($start)) && (strtotime($current) < strtotime($end))) {
    echo "current";
    }
    else {
    "not current";
    }
```